# Falla al probar la conexion con la base de datos desde php en CentosOS7

Tags: centos, lamp

El problema que tengo es que tengo problemas con la conexion a la base de datos desde php, tengo virtualizado CentosOS7 , le instale apache, mariadb 5.5 y php 5.4.16, los scripts normales de php si funcionan pero cuando hago una prueba para conectar una base de datos desde php no se puede hacer la conexion.

Comment: Pues vaya, espero que encuentres la información para arreglarlo en alguna parte.  Aquí, con toda esta información que nos has dado, solo podemos empezar a opinar e ir sacándote con cuentagotas los detalles que necesitamos para ayudarte, y lo siento, pero así no funciona este sitio (y no se si te das cuenta del tiempo que nos ocuparia a todos hacerlo, tanto a ti como a nosotros). Queremos ayudar, pero la pregunta debe ser mucho más precisa y concreta para ello. Lo entenderás si te lees [ask], [tour] y sobretodo [example], gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.